# C# WPF XAML multiple auto width or height

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For example:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Text="A text" Width="Auto"/>
```

Instead of setting the width as **Auto**, I want to set it as **2*Auto**, how to achieve it in XAML directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting it through column definitions of your grid? Then set HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" of your TextBox

```
   <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <TextBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="TextBox1" Text="A text" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your aim is here. Usually you let a container around the text box take care of that for you. One (hacky) way might be to use a grid with HorizontalContentAlignment=Stretch, and place a second TextBox in there with the text doubled and Visibility=Hidden.